# reading a drag and drop ordered list via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery-ui, html-lists

I have an application (drag and drop using JqueryUI.GridSort) that allows the user to upload photos, and then sort the photos in the order that they would like using drag and drop.

On page load, the user is prompted to upload photos which are posted to the next page. When they arrive on the next page my php script creates a `<ul id="sortable">` containing `<li>` for each of the files they uploaded. For each picture that they have uploaded to the site, a new `<li>` is created. Inside of that `<li>` is a `<img>` that sets the picture for `<li>` with the image they have uploaded.

My goal is to be able to "save" the order of the pictures after they have arranged them in the drag and drop interface. For example, once they have finished arranging and sorting the pictures in the order they want them in, I would like to be able to send them another page that creates an xml file ( I don't need help with the XML, only saving the order) with using the list that they created in the correct order.

After hours of tinkering with PHP, I have come to realization that because PHP is a serverside language, it cannot see what is sorted post render. So my question is, is there a way to have JavaScript or Ajax read the current order of the list, and post it to the next page? If you do know how, could you please provide an example of both the POST from one page, and the post receiving on the other? I am not very familiar with Ajax.

Thank you greatly for any assistance you could provide.

Sample Code (The contents of the foreach statement that creates a LI for each file uploaded)

```
 $imgID++;


echo '<li class="ui-state-default"><img id="'.$imgID.'"'.' src="user_files/'.$file_name.'" draggable="true" height="90" width="95"></li>';
```

EDIT

```
main page :


<script>
$('#my_form').on('submit', function() {
    var ordered_list = [];
    $("#sortable li img").each(function() {
        ordered_list.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });
    $("#ordered_list_data").val(JSON.stringify(ordered_list));
});
</script>
<div id="tesT">
<form id="my_form" action="update_data.php">
    <!-- other fields -->
    <input type="hidden" id="ordered_list_data"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Proceed to Step 2"></input>
</form>
</div>


update_data.php:

<?php
    // process other fields as normal
    if(isset($_POST['ordered_list_data'])) {
        $img_ordering = json_decode($_POST['ordered_list_data']);
echo "1";
    } else {
       echo "nodata";
    }
    // do things with the data

?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I built a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ycjp5k9e/) doing basically the same thing that David posted.

I added a piece to write out the result to a div on the page, so you can see what's going on:

```
<input type="button" id="savebutton" value="save"/>
<div id="output"></div>
<form id="listsaveform" method="POST" action="script.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="list" id="hiddenListInput" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
$( "#savebutton" ).click(function() { LISTOBJ.saveList(); });
});

var LISTOBJ = {
    saveList: function() {
        var listCSV = "";
        $( "#sortable li" ).each(function() {
            if (listCSV === "") {
                listCSV = $(this).text();
            } else {
                listCSV += "," + $(this).text();
            }
        });
        $("#output").text(listCSV);
        $("#hiddenListInput").val(listCSV);
        //$("#listsaveform").submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks good, and works exactly how I would like it, +1 for the JS fiddle. A second question. Once I have that order I can process the data however I would like . but since this isn't PHP I'm not sure how I would begin to put that into an XML . Is there a way to post that CSV, or the saved order to PHP so I can use simple XML? Or  will it stay in Jquery?

Comment: Yeah, the commented out line at the end of the Javascript block will actually post the CSV to your server (whatever the action on your form is - in my example script.php"). Then on the PHP side, you grab the value from $_POST['list'] and save it to your database.

Comment: Excellent. It seems to be working great. Is it possible to get the contents of the image src or ID as well?

Comment: You can do all kinds of things in the "each" loop. Using jQuery gives you a lot of options. http://api.jquery.com/attr/  Will let you grab attributes from the image.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a `<form>` you can do something like this (assuming jQuery is being used):

```
$('#my_form').on('submit', function() {
    var ordered_list = [];
    $("#sortable li img").each(function() {
        ordered_list.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });
    $("#ordered_list_data").val(JSON.stringify(ordered_list));
});
```

In essence, what you're doing is looping over the `<ul>`, fetching each `<img>` and appending the ids (in order of appearance) to an array. Arrays preserve ordering in JavaScript and JSON, so one can turn it into a JSON string using the `JSON.stringify` function, set it as the value of a `<input type="hidden">` field and then submit the form.

If you want to use AJAX, the functionality is very similar. However, instead of using an `onsubmit` (or `onclick`) you'd use [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Let's go with the `<form>` option since it's simpler. All told you'll have something similar to the above JS along with HTML like this:

```
<form id="my_form" method="post" action="./update_data.php">
    <!-- other fields -->
    <input type="hidden" name="ordered_list_data" id="ordered_list_data"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

Then, in `update_data.php` (or whatever your script is named):

```
<?php
    // process other fields as normal
    if(isset($_POST['ordered_list_data'])) {
        $img_ordering = json_decode($_POST['ordered_list_data']);
    } else {
        // handle case where there is no data
    }
    // do things with the data
?>
```

Comment: Great Answer, How would I go about passing the order to PHP so I can for example input it into SimpleXML? I am not very familiar with Jquery besides the UI. I'm still in the learning process you would day.

Comment: An event like this would go off when a user hit a `submit` button. In that case, it'd show up in PHP as `$_POST['ordered_list_data']` and `$_REQUEST['ordered_list_data']`. From there, you can use `json_decode($_POST['ordered_list_data']);` to get a PHP array from it.

Comment: I seem to having some issues. Would you be able to edit your answer with how you think the Post/request would work? Sorry for the extra work lol.

Comment: Excellent, Testing now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think I'm getting closer,
I just can't seem to get any Data. I copy and pasted your script, and form into the end of my html document, and then created the update_data.php page and added in your php snippet. upon hitting submit, I do not get any data however.

I will update my question with the edited code.

Comment: @RobertDickey I missed something very important (two things actually). I've updated my post with them. First, I forgot the `method="post"`. Second, I forgot that forms are submitted with the `name="whatever"` as the keys! Try adding `name="ordered_list_data"` to the hidden field and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Alright. I made the changes, and now it does tell me that there is data, but seems to be blank, or (possibly) im doing something wrong. 

if I try to echo the img_ordering, or the $_POST itself, I receive blank info, but it does tell me that POST is set. I think this is a problem on my end though.

Comment: @RobertDickey One last thing you could try would be attaching the event to a button's `'click'` instead of the form's `'submit'` and then calling $("#my_form").submit() at the end of the function.