# include javascript in value input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript variable I would like to send POST with a form on submit. The form has fields im sending as well. I tried to put it in the value field but I guess js doesn't work in there.

How can I send my js var with the form?

Comment: `$('#SomeFormField').val(SomeJSVariable);` ?

Comment: Show us what you tried and why it isn't working.

Comment: I answered a similar question recently:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732641/reading-a-drag-and-drop-ordered-list-via-javascript/17732956#17732956

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `hidden` input fields in your form.  A `hidden` input field will submit a value just like any other input, except the user will not see the value.  You can access and modify the `hidden` input field just like any other field in Javascript.

Example HTML

```
<form action="mypage.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="var1" value="abc" />
  <input type="text" name="var2" value="def" />
  <input id="myvar" type="hidden" name="var3" />
</form>
```

Example JS

```
var myJSVar = 'ghi';
//Using regular Javascript
document.getElementById('myvar').value = myJSVar;
//Using jQuery
$('#myvar').val(myJSVar);
```

Submitting the form now will produce the following inside of your `POST` variable:

`var1=abc&var2=def&var3=ghi`

For more information on hidden input types, you can read [this article from w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_hidden.asp)